# calculating multi inputs (jquery)

Tags: jquery

In my website I have an option to add (multiple times) an input with a button, using this code,

```
$("#add_new_detail").click(function() { 
    $("#det_add_area").append('
        <div id="no_'+i+'"><table><tr><td> '+i+' </td><td> 
            <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][details]" /> </td><td> 
            <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][amount]" value="0" /> </td><td> 
            <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][price_real]" value="0" /> </td><td> 
            <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][price_user]" value="0" /> </td><td> 
            <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][total_price]" value="0" DISABLED  /> 
            </td><td> <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][total_price_for_user]" value="0" DISABLED  /> </td><td>
            <div class="delete_line" onClick="re(\'no_'+i+'\')"> delete </div></td></tr></table></div>
  '); 
  i++; 
});
```

Now, every time I click the button it really creates a new line of inputs. That is working perfect.
Now I'm trying to calculate between the inputs, I'm trying to enter a number into

> det['+i+'][amount]

and to double it with (math)

> det['+i+'][price_real]

and to post the result in

> det['+i+'][total_price]

now I have no idea how can I interact with these specific fields(which getting created by the button click) - every line has it own amount,price_real,total_price ...  how can I make this calculate with onKeyUp ?
if someone can give me an idea how am I moving on from this point I'll be grateful.

thanks :)

Comment: You should avoid special characters, just have `det_0_total_price`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA, don't forget I've to use it after this in the server side, so everytime I make new line it gives it a uniqe id. so i'll be able to interact with it in the server side after I submit the form.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... I have modified the `name` attribute to `id`. Also used `_` instead of `[`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rM42/)**

Whenever you change `amount` or `price_real`, the corresponding `total_price` will change `(total_price = amount * price_real)`.

**jQuery**

```
$("#add_new_detail").on("click", function() { 
    $("#det_add_area").append('<div id="no_'+i+'"><table><tr><td> '+i+' </td><td> \
            <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_details" /> </td><td> \
            <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_amount" value="0" /> </td><td> \
            <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_price_real" value="0" /> </td><td> \
            <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_price_user" value="0" /> </td><td> \
            <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_total_price" value="0" DISABLED  /> \
            </td><td> <input type="text" id="det_'+i+'_total_price_for_user" value="0" DISABLED  /> </td><td>\
            <div class="delete_line" onClick="re(\'no_'+i+'\')"> delete </div></td></tr></table></div>\
    '); 

    $("#det_" + i + "_amount").on("change", function() { 
        calculate(this); 
    });

    $("#det_" + i + "_price_real").on("change", function() { 
        calculate(this); 
    });

    i++;
});

function calculate(e) {
    j = $(e).attr('id').split("_")[1]
    total = $("#det_" + j + "_amount").val() * $("#det_" + j + "_price_real").val();
    $("#det_" + j + "_total_price").val(total);
}
```

Comment: I still can't do anything with that ... it doesnt calculate or do anything onChange, I tried to check with - alert(), but it still doesnt work ..

and btw if I use `det_'+i+'_total_price` it will be the same when I get it in the server side (PHP) as array? in $_POST ?

Comment: @user1927064 Added Live Demo. If you need to post the values, then just add `id` as a new attribute instead of replacing `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a unique id to every input you want to use, as selecting by id is really staightforward (as opposed to selecting by name). Then you'll be able to use $("#theId").val() to get to the input value of the text box, and $("#theId").val(new_Value) to set it.

Also, guessing from code, you're going to use square brackets for your ids. In that case, you should escape it in the jquery selector, like so: $("det\[1\]\[total_price\]")

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hey, you'r idea doesnt really make sense because might be a milion inputs, I cant give a name to it ... every time I'll make a new line of inputs all of them will be with the same name, and I've to make a calculate for every specific line on inputs.

maybe I didn't understande you right, can you show me a little example how can I give to them a unique id and use it ?
thanks!

Comment: To add an id, just change  <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][details]" /> </td><td>  to
 <input type="text" name="det['+i+'][details]" id=name="det['+i+'][details]" /> </td><td>
There are cleaner ways to do it, and can show them, if you'd like, but this one will also do the trick.
Once you have the ids in place, you can use a simple loop - something like:

for(var j=0; j<i;j++)
{
 var result = $("det\\["+j+"\\]\\[amount\\]").val() * $("det\\["+j+"\\]\\[amount\\]").val();
 $("det\\["+j+"\\]\\[total_price\\]").val(result);
 
}

Comment: well, I tried to play with what you told me, and I tried
`<input type="text" name="det['+i+'][amount]" id="det['+i+'][amount]" onChange="da(this.name)" value="0" />`

heres da() ->

`function da(a)
{
 var myarr = a.split("[");
 // holding the input id.
 myarr = myarr[1].charAt(0);
 
 alert($("det\[2\]\[amount\]").val());
}`

and all I get is 
> undefined

I cant even rich the value of the input :S
thanks!

Comment: even when I try manually:
`alert($("det[2][amount]").val() + " - " + myarr);`
I get
> undefined - 2